# Android External Storage BufferedWriter doesn't accept NewLine

Tags: android, file

i have problem with file writing. I want to create OnClick method of button that add line to file on sdcard but instead it delete previous line and put all content in place of current one. In result i got only the Text i put at the last click of Button, here is my code:

```
if (txtFile.createNewFile() || txtFile.isFile()) {
                        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                        try {
                            fOut = new FileOutputStream(txtFile);
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                        BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(myOutWriter);
                        EditText desc__ = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditTExt);
                        try {
                            bwriter.newLine();
                            bwriter.write(lat+"|"+lng+"|"+desc__.getText().toString()+"|"+f+"|"+position);

                            bwriter.close();
                            myOutWriter.close();
                            fOut.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        /* handle directory here */
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please rewrite your **FileOutputStream** constructor as

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

here is suggests that your file will be opened in the append mode which will solve your first problem..

secondly if you want to add new line to the file use **`"\r\n"`** string

```
e.g. fos.write("\r\n".getBytes());
```

Hope this helps..